# Import third party library mssql with webpack angular

Tags: sql-server, node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I want to import and use npm mssql but without success.

My environment is :

- angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16
- node 6.3.1
- webpack@2.1.0-beta.22

I install @types/mssql with the command line

```
npm install @types/mssql --savedev
```

I install `mssql` (I've tested the latest and version 3.1.0) with the command

```
npm install mssql --save
```

I test this code to connect to a local SQL Server:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Connection, Request } from 'mssql';

@Injectable()
export class MssqlService { 
  configsql = {
      server: 'server\\SQL2K16EXP',
      database: 'BDD_160219',
      user: 'sa',
      password: 'pass',
      port: 1433
  };


  constructor() {
    let connection: Connection;
    connection = new Connection(this.configsql, err=> {console.log(err);});

   }

  Test() {    
    console.log(22);
  }
}
```

I get an error ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find module "."

I test also with an

```
import * as sql from 'mssql';
```

instead of

```
import { Connection, Request } from 'mssql';
```

Without success maybe I mess something up, but I don't know what :/

Thanks in advance :)

Johan